# Wrapping Multiple Elements (jQuery)

Tags: jquery, dom

I've this piece of HTML:

```
div.content
  div.one
    content
  div.two
    content
  div.three
    content
```

I want to **add two divs on top and bottom** and **wrap one div** around it so it becomes:

```
div.top
div.wrapper
  div.content
    div.one
      content
    div.two
      content
    div.three
      content
div.bottom
```

I'm aware of the several wrap selectors (innerWrap, wrapAll etc..) but I'm not sure how to wrap 2 divs.

The following jQuery might work, but is there a better way to write it?

```
$('content').wrap('<div class="wrapper"></div');
$('.wrapper').before('<div class="top"></div>');
$('.wrapper').after('<div class="bottom"></div>');
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would do it in one line to minimize lookup:

```
$('content')
     .before('<div class="top"></div>')
     .after('<div class="bottom"></div>')
     .wrap('<div class="wrapper"></div>');
```